# How to identify julia packages that hold back newer versions of other packages?

Tags: julia, package, versioning, package-managers

Is there a builtin way to know which dependencies are causing other packages to fall behind the current release?

Recently I hat this issue:
https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/issues/246#issuecomment-384943473

After a `Pkg.update()` I expected to see all current versions:

```
Pkg.available("Flux")
14-element Array{VersionNumber,1}:
 v"0.1.0"
 v"0.1.1"
 v"0.2.0"
 v"0.2.1"
 v"0.2.2"
 v"0.3.0"
 v"0.3.1"
 v"0.3.2"
 v"0.3.3"
 v"0.3.4"
 v"0.4.0"
 v"0.4.1"
 v"0.5.0"
 v"0.5.1"
```

but just was able to select from (`v"0.5.1"` was yet released):

```
julia> Pkg.available("Flux")
12-element Array{VersionNumber,1}:
 v"0.1.0"
 v"0.1.1"
 v"0.2.0"
 v"0.2.1"
 v"0.2.2"
 v"0.3.0"
 v"0.3.1"
 v"0.3.2"
 v"0.3.3"
 v"0.3.4"
 v"0.4.0"
 v"0.4.1"
```

I started from sratch with a new empty `JULIA_PKGDIR`, but thats annoying for different reasons:

- downloading all packages again
- creating new symlinks to packages for local projects which are not in `JULIA_PKGDIR`

  - NOTE: one can also use the [`LOAD_PATH`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Modules_and_packages#How_does_Julia_find_a_module?) variable in `~/.juliarc.jl` to load local projects.
- still not knowing what caused the problem

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there's not perfectly correct way currently, but a script posted on Discourse could help: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-find-package-preventing-others-from-updating/8235

Comment: `grep PackageName ~/.julia/v0.6/**/REQUIRE` from @Tamas_Papp seems quite useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Pkg.update("Flux")` will often tell you which packages are holding back the update.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't :(